# Dynamic creation of rows in jsp table

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp.In jsp page I am showing the table with 6 columns in that 2 columns are selected values. Values will come from Spring MVC controller.Based on the selection price,discount will come by AJAX call. My requirement is to give **Buy More** link,If he click that link one row should come with 6 columns and do the same process selecting values and price calculations.And **Delete Row** button should delete the selected row.

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with Javascript/Jquery, the sample code is given below-

```
function addRow()
            {
                var n=$("#elementCount").val();
                var i=$('#rowid'+(n-1));
                i.clone(true).attr('id','rowid'+(n)).insertAfter(i);
                var p="#txtname"+(n-1);
                var no="txtname"+(n);
                $('#rowid'+(n)).find('.c').attr('id',no);
                $('#rowid'+(n)).find('.c').attr('name',no);
                $('#rowid'+(n)).find('.c').attr('value','');

                $('#rowid'+(n)).find('.b').attr('id',"txtprc"+(n));
                $('#rowid'+(n)).find('.b').attr('name',"txtprc"+(n));
                $('#rowid'+(n)).find('.b').attr('value','');

                n++;

                $("#elementCount").val(n);
            }
```

where elementcount is the id of a hidden field which contains value=number of rows.
the function with i clones the row and inserts it after current row.
every row will have the id in increasing manner i.e. rowid1, rowid2 and so on....